# How to share shoutcast song on facebook wall

Tags: facebook, shoutcast

I have a page on my site with integrated KAST player streaming with shoutcast. Now I want when a user shares this url on facebook wall it should show audio/video player instead if site link. it should be shared just like youtube video.

I have tried with og video/audio meta tags but its not working. I used an php code to get current track details and used them in og tags.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible.  Facebook does not currently allow developers to have an embedded player into the Facebook wall.  Only some of the major players have this ability.  Hopefully they will open this up in the future.

Comment: Agree. Some time ago it was possible to embed Adobe Flash players playing radio streams into the wall, but now Flash is not in favor anymore, so I think that's not working now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a service that automatically posts Shoutcast songs to Facebook, it posts the name of the song and the artist, and can also dynamically post a link to the song in YouTube. It doesn't allow you to listen within Facebook though, which I think is what you are asking. As mentioned, this now only seems to be allowed for some of the big players such as Sound cloud.

See autopo.st for the service mentioned above, it's a paid for service.